# nested condition in mongodb aggregation

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection `product` which looks like this.

```js
{
  should_show: {
    type: String,
    enum: ['always', 'never', 'on_date'],
    default: 'always',
  },
  show_start_date: { type: Date },
  show_end_date: { type: Date },
  categories: [{ type: ObjectId }],
  price: number,
}
```

`find` condition like this works fine when I find many products.

```js
const condition = {
  '$and': [
    { '$and': [ { categories: '61bdd930fb1dfb1f65a21f13' } ] },
    {
      '$or': [
        { should_show: 'always' },
        {
          should_show: 'on_date',
          show_start_date: { '$lt': 2022-01-03T08:56:19.589Z },
          show_end_date: { '$gt': 2022-01-03T08:56:19.589Z }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
Products.find(condition)
```

But I changed my business logic to use `Model.aggregate()` instead of `Model.find()

(because I have to use `allowdiskuse` option)

```js
const condition = {
  '$and': [
    { '$and': [ { categories: '61bdd930fb1dfb1f65a21f13' } ] },
    {
      '$or': [
        { should_show: 'always' },
        {
          should_show: 'on_date',
          show_start_date: { '$lt': 2022-01-03T08:56:19.589Z },
          show_end_date: { '$gt': 2022-01-03T08:56:19.589Z }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

Products.aggregate([
  { $match: condition },
])
```

And returned results is always empty array `[]`

I changed my condition simpler like this

```js
const condition = {
  '$and': [ { categories: '61bdd930fb1dfb1f65a21f13' } ],
  '$or': [
    { should_show: 'always' },
    {
      should_show: 'on_date',
      show_start_date: { '$lt': 2022-01-03T08:56:50.161Z },
      show_end_date: { '$gt': 2022-01-03T08:56:50.161Z }
    }
  ]
}

Products.aggregate([
  { $match: condition },
])
```

but still returns empty array.

How should I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Self Answer:

I have to pass ObjectId by explicit ObjectId type, not string.

```js
const condition = {
  '$and': [
    { '$and': [{
      // like this:
      categories: Mongoose.Types.ObjectId('61bdd930fb1dfb1f65a21f13'),
    }] },
    {
      '$or': [
        { should_show: 'always' },
        {
          should_show: 'on_date',
          show_start_date: { '$lt': 2022-01-03T08:56:19.589Z },
          show_end_date: { '$gt': 2022-01-03T08:56:19.589Z }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

Products.aggregate([
  { $match: condition },
])
```